# Google Play Developer Console - Cannot update app, says app title is already in use by package name... my own package name

Tags: android, console, google-play, updating

Having real problems updating any apps on Google Play Developer Console.

This is what I have done 2 or 3 times..

- Increment the version code in manifest
- Changed the version name is manifest to reflect this
- Keep package exactly the same
- Tried keeping exported .apk name exactly the same
- Tried charging exported .apk name
- Keystore and passwords exactly the same
- On Console, clicked upload new app, typed same title exactly and click upload
- Error comes up saying title (of my existing app) is currently in use by ,   the package name of my existing app.
- This is the same for both English languages, US and UK.

One point, I was able to do one successful update, then I changed my company name, since then I have not been able to update.

- Though I did create a new Test app, from scratch, exported it with a new keystore.
- Tried to update through this process and exactly the same happened.

Would genuinely appreciate any help on this... tis accelerating the arrival of some new grey hairs!

Comment: If you're getting prompted to enter a title then it sounds like you're clicking the wrong button. Can you take a screenshot of the button you're trying to use to perform the upload, perhaps?

Comment: Ahah, thank you for this newbie question, I had exactly the same problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be clicking "upload new app". You need to click the APK section on the left and then the "Upload new APK" button.

Comment: No prob. Anything to help a fellow Android-ler! (You can help by downloading & commenting my App from the Play Store ;) )